# How to use emotion with nextjs ? Hydration error

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, emotion, hydration

Im trying to create a static blog using nextjs.

I want to use [@emotion/styled](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled) to style code blocks but I am running into to some hydration issues.

I have created a custom `<Code>` component to style code snippets in my blog.

I am using @ts-stack/markdown to parse the blog content and add a simple block rule for displaying code snippets following this example [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ts-stack/markdown#example-of-setting-a-simple-block-rule).

#### I am getting this error in the console:

```
Warning: Prop `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` did not match. 
Server: "<p>Some text</p>\n<div class=\"css-129r3k1\"><div class=\"css-52td2g\">JS</div><div class=\"css-pxcwrp\">\n<pre><code>const mycode = \"\"\n</code></pre>\n</div></div>" 
Client: "<p>Some text</p>\n<style data-emotion=\"css 129r3k1\">.css-129r3k1{margin:0 auto;position:relative;max-width:850px;}</style><div class=\"css-129r3k1\"><style data-emotion=\"css 52td2g\">.css-52td2g{position:absolute;right:0;border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;background-color:#f2f2fd;padding:6px;width:-webkit-fit-content;width:-moz-fit-content;width:fit-content;min-width:50px;font-size:var(--normal-text-size);text-align:center;font-weight:bold;color:purple;-webkit-transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(-100%);-moz-transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(-100%);-ms-transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(-100%);transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(-100%);}</style><div class=\"css-52td2g\">JS</div><style data-emotion=\"css pxcwrp\">.css-pxcwrp{margin-top:32px;font-size:var(--feature-text-size);padding:32px;background-color:#f2f2fd;border-radius:12px;overflow-x:auto;line-height:28px;}</style><div class=\"css-pxcwrp\">\n<pre><code>const mycode = \"\"\n</code></pre>\n</div></div>"
```

It looks like the server generated code correctly puts the styles in the head element but when the client renders, it wants to put the style tags inline with the content.

I am not sure why this is happening....

#### Here is my code:

This is the custom `<Code>` component:

```
import emotion from "@emotion/styled"
import { FC } from "react"
type valueof<T> = T[keyof T]

export const LANGS = ["ts", "js"] as const
export type SupportedLangs = valueof<typeof LANGS>

type Props = {
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML?:
    | {
        __html: string
      }
    | undefined
  lang: SupportedLangs
}

export const Code: FC<Props> = ({
  children,
  lang,
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML,
}) => (
  <Wrapper>
      <Lang>{lang.toString().toUpperCase()}</Lang>
    <Content dangerouslySetInnerHTML={dangerouslySetInnerHTML}>
      {children}
    </Content>
  </Wrapper>
)

const Lang = emotion.div`
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  background-color: #f2f2fd;
  padding: 6px;
  width: fit-content;
  min-width: 50px;
  font-size: var(--normal-text-size);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: purple;
  transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(-100%);
`

export const Content = emotion.div`
  margin-top: 32px;
  font-size: var(--feature-text-size);
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: #f2f2fd;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  line-height: 28px;
`
export const Wrapper = emotion.div`
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 850px;
`
```

This is my `pages/posts/[id].tsx` file.

```
import fs from "fs"
import { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps } from "next"
import { Marked } from "@ts-stack/markdown"
import matter, { GrayMatterFile } from "gray-matter"
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server"
import { ErrorMessage } from "../../components/errorMessage"
import { Code, LANGS, SupportedLangs } from "../../components/code"

Marked.setBlockRule(
  /^@@@ *(\w+):?(js|ts)?\n([\s\S]+?)\n@@@/,
  function (execArr) {
    const channel = execArr?.[1]
    const param1 = execArr?.[2]
    const content = execArr?.[3]

    switch (channel) {
      case "code": {
        return (
          ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
            <Code
              lang={param1 as SupportedLangs}
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: Marked.parse(content) }}
            ></Code>
          )
        )
      }
    }
  }
)

type Props = { id: string } & GrayMatterFile<string>

const postsPath = "./posts"

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<Props, { id: string }> = ({
  params,
}) => {
  const file = fs.readFileSync(postsPath + `/${params!.id}.md`).toString()
  const parsed = matter(file)
  return Promise.resolve({
    props: {
      id: params!.id,
      ...parsed,
      orig: parsed.orig.toString(),
      content: Marked.parse(parsed.content),
    },
  })
}

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => ({
  fallback: false,
  paths: fs
    .readdirSync(postsPath)
    .map((x) => "/posts/" + x.substr(0, x.length - 3)),
})

export default function Post({ content, data }: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{data.date}</p>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }}></div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

My example post markdown file:

````
---
date: 2022/02/14
---

Some text

@@@ code:js
\```
const mycode = ""
\```
@@@
````